# Getting a result from a prepared statement into a variable

Tags: mysql, variables, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, prepared-statement

I've been trying to get a result from a prepared statement into a variable. I've looked around and found something to what I was trying to do however I'm not sure how to implement it correctly. This is how I've tried but when I run it inserts blanks into the table.

```
Drop procedure if exists campaignTEST;

DELIMITER  $$

Create procedure campaignTEST(in userID smallint)
sp_Campaign17:BEGIN

Declare activityCount mediumint;
Declare lastActivityDate DateTime;

Declare TableName varchar(64);

SET TableName = 'user_activity_';  
SET TableName = concat(TableName, convert(userID,char(64)));

SET @lastActivityDateTest = ('SELECT @date := date from ' ,TableName, ' order by date desc limit 1;');  
    PREPARE stmt FROM @lastActivityDateTest;  
    EXECUTE stmt;  
    Select @date AS lastActivityDate;  
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @activityCountTest = ('Select @count := count(*) from ' ,TableName, ' where Month(date) > Month(Date_SUB(CURRENT_date, Interval 1 month));');  
    PREPARE stmt FROM @activityCountTest;   
    EXECUTE stmt;  
    select @count as activityCount;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

INSERT INTO email_tracker
(activity_date,  allocated)
Values
(lastActivityDate, activityCount)

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I would use select..into and SET activitycount BTW you can select 2 columns into 2 variables.

Comment: I've tried that however the tables I'm pulling from the table name changes based on the user that is passed into the procedure. Which requires a dynamic sql statement, hence using a prepared statement, Can you select 2 variables even if the 1 is a count of a table?

Comment: Ahh it seems I may have miss understood what you were saying.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working with the help of a friend.

These statements,

```
SET @lastActivityDateTest = ('SELECT @date := date from ' ,TableName, ' order by date desc limit 1;');  
    PREPARE stmt FROM @lastActivityDateTest;  
    EXECUTE stmt;  
    Select @date AS lastActivityDate;  
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @activityCountTest = ('Select @count := count(*) from ' ,TableName, ' where Month(date) > Month(Date_SUB(CURRENT_date, Interval 1 month));');  
    PREPARE stmt FROM @activityCountTest;   
    EXECUTE stmt;  
    select @count as activityCount;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

INSERT INTO email_tracker
(activity_date,  allocated)
Values
(lastActivityDate, activityCount)
```

Should have been this

```
SET @statement = CONCAT('SELECT date into @result from ', TableName, ' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1');
PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @statement = CONCAT('SELECT count(*) into @result2 from ', TableName, ' where Month(date) > Month(Date_SUB(CURRENT_date, Interval 1 month));');
PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

INSERT INTO email_tracker
(activity_date,  allocated)
Values
(@result, @result2)
```